# howto get HttpException statusCode from HttpException variable

Tags: error-handling, laravel-5

I have this exception:

```
HttpException {#689 ▼
    -statusCode: 403
    -headers: []
    #message: ""
    #code: 0
    #file: "/var/www/hqse/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php"
   #line: 905
  -trace: {▶}
}
```

I can not get the statusCode of the exception.  I need to get "403".

The `getCode()` function returns 0.

Instead if I do:

```
$exc->statusCode
```

it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get `statusCode` there is method `$exc->getStatusCode()`.